# How to call onLocationChanged when location has not changed with LocationClient?

Tags: android, android-location

I have successfully implemented the android location example http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

I can request location updates via button click and the onLocationChanged method will be triggered to update a map view with the current location.

But consider following problem. When the phones location does not change, onLocationChange will not be triggered anymore. When the user touches the map view and swipes to another location manually, another location request will not trigger onLocationChanged and the map view will not get the current location because the phones position has not changed.

My question is, how can I receive a location in onLocationChanged at 0 location difference? I am using LocationClient and LocationRequest classes and not LocationManager, so this wont work:

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates(best, 10000, 1, locationListener);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in that case you can invoke `getLastKnownLocation` but you have to detect that state, simply try to wrap your class that provide you location and once time it is update with RequestLocationUpdates listening on updates and once when it is not triggered it invoke getLastKnownLocation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Rafik991 I know, but I cannot know if onLocationChanged will be triggered or not. Is it safe to just request both lastLocation and request update?

Comment: Look on my draft below ;)

Answer (score 0):

use `getLastLocation()` mehod of locationClient it will give you last known location, however it may be null sometime, I observe in some devices it is returning null when I restart the device and call that function before starting gps or location client method.

Comment: but how do you distinguish the situations where onlocationchanged is not called because location has not changed from cases where it is not called because you don't get a gps signal and gps can't find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

in that case you can invoke `getLastKnownLocation` but you have to detect that state, simply try to wrap your class that provide you location and once time it is update with R
`requestLocationUpdates`listening on updates and once when it is not triggered it invoke `getLastKnownLocation`

so simply you can wrap it with some class that contains `lastLocation` or best `location` field

```
public class MyLocationProvider implements LocalisationListener{
   private Location bestLocation = null;
   private LocationManager locationManager;
   //constructor and all that stuff...

   public Location getBestLocation(){
     if(bestLocation == null)
       return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation();
     else 
       return bestLocation;

}

//locationListener methods... that should save their result in `bestLocation` field.

}
```

This is simple draft of my idea.... I didn't compile it ;)

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: This wont work because bestLocation is not null when onLocationChanged was triggered

Comment: so simply you can initialize it with `lastLocation`